# Create div dynamically based on selected Div

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my demo project i am having Division like,

```
<div id ="Controls">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Test" Width="200px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width ="200px"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Like this lot of divisions are there.

My Need is, Whenever i am selecting any division and i can add any new division below or above to that division.

For that i am having one DDL with the list contains, "Add Below, Add Above" etc.

1. By selecting one division (Ex, Above division) then i have to choose option from DDL like "Add above or Add below" etc. Then i have to click add button. After clicking that button one new division should generate based on ddl Selection corresponding to that division.

How can i do this. can anyone please guide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to do this on postback or just add several DOM-items with javascript?

Comment: Not with postback. By using Javascript, Jquery etc. What my need is it have to return ID of the DIV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use http://api.jquery.com/after/.

```
var divTag = document.createElement("div");
divTag.Id="yournewdivId";    
$("#Controls").after(divTag);
```

Use http://api.jquery.com/before/ for adding div to the top of current div.